# Difference between Hatcher exercise 1.2.5 and Example 1.22

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification

> Let $X\subset\Bbb R^2$ be a connected graph that is the union of a finite number of straight-line segments. Show that $\pi_1(X)$ is free with a basis consisting of loops formed by the boundaries of the bounded complementary regions of $X$, joined to a basepoint by suitably chosen paths in $X$. [Assume the Jordan curve theorem for polygonal simple closed curves, which is equivalent to the case that $X$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$].

I don't know the difference between this problem and Exercise 1.22 in [Hatcher's textbook](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf).

I think for given graph $X$, choose a spanning tree $T$. Then by definition of spanning tree, for each edges $e_\alpha\in X-T$, if we add this to $T$, then it forms a cycle. Now, as in Exercise 1.22, we define an open neighborhood $A_\alpha$ of $T\cup e_\alpha$ that deformation retracts to $T\cup e_\alpha$.
Now apply van Kampen to union of $A_\alpha$'s we get $\pi_1(X)$ a free group with a basis correspond to $e_\alpha$'s. This is same as what we desired by the Jordan curve theorem.

I think the proof is essentially same as the proof given in Example 1.22. Am I misunderstanding the point of this exercise?